# Blender interface appears gray?

Tags: interface, theme

I'm not sure what's going on, but today in the morning when I opened blender it had turned gray from black.

I don't think it's affecting any type of performance, but it is not feeling right while working, is there anything I can do to revert this change?

I'm using Blender 2.50

Comment: Blender 5? Do you mean 2.65, 2.55 or 2.50?

Comment: 2.5, @GiantCowFilms

Comment: I'm Guessing that what every you did to make it black was reverted.

Comment: I don't know what to do to make it black, though made a check in the settings, but that wasn't of any use

Comment: Blender is gray by default. Is it possible you were using the bundled *Back to Black* theme? Try enabling it in *File menu > User preferences > Themes > Presets > Back to black*.

Comment: Ok, that did the job, @gandalf3

Answer (score 1):

Blender is gray by default:

[image]

So it sounds like the theme you were using was somehow reverted.

There is a black theme bundled with blender called *Back to Black*. If you select it in *File menu > User preferences* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) *> Themes > Presets*, then blender looks like this:

[image]

To set this as your default theme, click *Saver user settings* at the bottom of the user preferences:

[image]